# How can I use Django model filter to query objects from my database if a fieldname is present in a string

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

How can I use django query for objects by checking if it's fieldname is present in a string using objects.filter(). Like, if I wanted to filter using a fieldname named "Foo" if it was in the string "Foo Bar". I tried the following line but of course it does not work:

```
# name = Foo
obj.objects.filter(name__in='Foo Bar') # Empty Query list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all substrings and use `in`:

```
from itertools import combinations

my_str = 'Foo Bar'
substrings = [my_str[x:y] for x, y in combinations(range(len(my_str) + 1), r = 2)]
obj.objects.filter(name__in=substrings)
```